# How to perform sql joins in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following two models

```
class MyTable < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :my_table_joins, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end

class MyTableJoin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :some_column, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :my_table
end
```

I have following code in controller

```
  def index
    @my_table_data = MyTable.all
    render(json: @my_table_data) && return unless @my_table_data.empty?
    render_error(:not_found, 'something...')
  end
```

It returns following data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "SOME_NAME1",
    "created_at": "2017-09-28T18:51:51.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-28T18:51:51.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "SOME_NAME2",
    "created_at": "2017-09-28T18:51:51.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-28T18:51:51.000Z"
  },
]
```

I want to join table MyTableJoin with MyTable and produce data as follows:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "SOME_NAME1",
        "created_at": "2017-09-28T18:51:51.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-28T18:51:51.000Z"
        "access_group_joins": [
           {
             "some_column": 1
             "some_column_type": "some data"
             "created_at": "2017-01-01 12:00:00",
             "updated_at": "2017-01-01 12:00:00"
           },
            ... ...
 ]
      }
        {
          "id": 2
          ... ...
        }]
```

Basically i want to join both tables and returning all data from MyTable and specific set of columns from MyTableJoin. How can i achieve that?

I tried to create scope as follows

```
scope :with_joins_data, joins(:my_table_joins)
```

But trying to figure out how can i select just the columns i need from my_columns_table

Comment: Why not just set up a json template that sets the structure you need e.g. http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl

Comment: Yeah.. or jbuilder.. unless you want to write the sql query with select statement.

Comment: Thanks, i'll create views. Can you tell me how do i perform the joining part though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to go with the [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) idea, you could create a view with the following after you've added/configured the gem in your project:

```
json.array! @my_table_data do |data|
  json.id data.id
  json.name data.name
  json.created_at data.created_at
  json.updated_at data.updated_at

  json.access_group_joins @my_table_data.my_table_joins do |join_data|
    json.some_column join_data.id
    json.some_column_type join_data.name
    json.created_at join_data.created_at
    json.updated_at join_data.updated_at
  end
end
```

There are a lot of different way you could construct this. The above is one of them. You could also use `partial!` or `extract!`.

If you need to load all of those resources, it would be better if you ran `MyTable.includes(:my_table_joins)` instead of `MyTable.all`.

Hope that helps.